# How much gear will the AT eat?

Tags: gear, appalachian-trail, thru-hike

We're planning on hiking the AT, and [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/am-i-likely-to-need-multiple-pairs-of-boots-on-the-at) prompted me to ask:

What gear should we expect to replace, and how often, on the Appalachian Trail?

Assume that we know basic gear maintenance and can patch a tent instead of replacing the whole thing. ;)

Edit:  It occurs to me that gear to replace implies a lot of understanding about what's being carried so here's what we'll carry:  Tent, sleeping bag, ground pad, clothes, shoes, poles, packs, stove, raingear, knives

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you treat your gear well, it will almost all last a whole thru-hike.

**Rain Jacket**  If you have a bad year, you can have 80+ days of rain, and the shoulder straps of your backpack will wear out (delaminate usually) the shoulders of your rain jacket.

**Shoes** are covered over in the [other question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/am-i-likely-to-need-multiple-pairs-of-boots-on-the-at) pretty thoroughly I'd say.

**Pants**:  If you wear pants, chances are you'll go through a couple pairs.  Usually the ankles are the part that goes, followed by the knees/groin.

**Socks**:  Depending on what type you go with, you'll go through quite a few pairs.  If you think of durability when choosing socks, it could be a wise choice.  [Darn Tough](http://darntough.com/) socks are a staple for AT hikers.

Beyond that, I'll just say that a lot of your gear will be heavily worn by the AT.  Putting 150 nights on all your gear is more than a lifetime for most hikers.  I would say you'll end up retiring at least some of these:  all your daily worn clothes, tent, backpack, all waterproof stuff sacks (will no longer be waterproof), sleeping bag, insulated jacket, and rain pants.

I've heard from various thru-hikers, and it's a pretty wide range that people experience.  I know some people that have their [triple crown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Crown_of_Hiking) who used essentially the same set of gear the whole way and others who changed everything after each trail.  Personally, I had to replace my backpack and stuff sacks after the Pacific Crest Trail, and then I thought all my clothes were fine, but they fell apart within days of starting the Continental Divide Trail.

Answer (score 1):

Although some of the articles there appear to require payment, [BackpackingLight](http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/gearchecklists.html) have lots of gear lists for different conditions, including both long and short trips.

(This [list](http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/forums/thread_display.html?forum_thread_id=33333) specifically refers to the AT)